# Camera position for endless game in ThreeJs

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm studying Three.js and I'm tryng to do my first game: and endless game.

I have read [this article](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-simple-3d-endless-runner-game-using-three-js--cms-29157) and the purpose is to do something very similar.
The protagonist (the hero) is a blue ball that rolls towards the "infinity" and must avoid some obstacles that gradually arise in front of him. The user can avoid these obstacles by guiding the ball to the left or right and jumping (the idea is to use the keyboard and in particular the left/right arrow keys and the space bar to jump).

Here is my idea:
[image]

I want to follow the idea of the article but not to copy the code (I want to understand it).
This is what I've done so far:

```js
let sceneWidth = window.innerWidth;
let sceneHeight = window.innerHeight;
let canvas;
let camera;
let scene;
let renderer;
let dom;
let sun;
let hero;
let ground;
let clock;
let spotLight;
let ambientLight;

init();

function init() {
  createScene();
  showHelpers();
  update();
}

/**
 * Set up scene.
 */
function createScene() {
  clock = new THREE.Clock();
  clock.start();
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  window.scene = scene;

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, sceneWidth / sceneHeight, 0.1, 1000);
  camera.position.set(0, 0, 0);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
  renderer.setClearColor(0x333f47, 1);
  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
  renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;
  renderer.setSize(sceneWidth, sceneHeight);

  canvas = renderer.domElement;
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);

  // const orbitControls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, canvas);

  addGround();
  addHero();
  addLight();

  camera.position.set(0, -1, 0.6);
  camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

  window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize, false);
}

/**
 * Show helper.
 */
function showHelpers() {
  const axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(5);
  // scene.add(axesHelper);

  const spotLightHelper = new THREE.SpotLightHelper(spotLight);
  scene.add(spotLightHelper);
}

/**
 * Add ground to scene.
 */
function addGround() {
  const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 4);
  const material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: 0xcccccc,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
  });
  ground = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  ground.position.set(0, 1, 0);
  ground.receiveShadow = true;
  scene.add(ground);
}

/**
 * Add hero to scene.
 */
function addHero() {
  var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.03, 32, 32);
  var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: 0x3875d8,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
  });
  hero = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  hero.receiveShadow = true;
  hero.castShadow = true;
  scene.add(hero);
  hero.position.set(0, -0.62, 0.03);
}

/**
 * Add light to scene.
 */
function addLight() {
  // spot light
  spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
  spotLight.position.set(2, 30, 0);
  spotLight.angle = degToRad(10);
  spotLight.castShadow = true;
  spotLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;
  spotLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024;
  spotLight.shadow.camera.near = 1;
  spotLight.shadow.camera.far = 4000;
  spotLight.shadow.camera.fov = 45;
  scene.add(spotLight);

  // ambient light
  ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x303030, 2);
  scene.add(ambientLight);
}

/**
 * Call game loop.
 */
function update() {
  render();
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

/**
 * Render the scene.
 */
function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

/**
 * On window resize, render again the scene.
 */
function onWindowResize() {
  sceneHeight = window.innerHeight;
  sceneWidth = window.innerWidth;
  renderer.setSize(sceneWidth, sceneHeight);
  camera.aspect = sceneWidth / sceneHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}

/**
 * Degree to radiants
 */
function degToRad(degree) {
  return degree * (Math.PI / 180);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/utnevali/ay4cf06g/2/))

I'm having several problems, the first is the position of objects and the camera.

I would like to be able to position the plane so that the minor side is positioned at the beginning of the screen (the entire plane must therefore be visible, there must not be a hidden part).

I would like the ball to be positioned horizontally in the middle and vertically almost at the beginning of the floor (in short, as shown in the figure) and with the shadow projected onto the plane. Each object must have the shadow projected onto the plane.
I'm using a spotlight and Lambert materials so the shade should be there, but there is not. Why?

I don't even understand how to position objects.
I understood that the point `(0, 0, 0)` is the center of the screen.
I would like the ground to be at `y=0` and all the other objects are positioned above as if they were resting.
My code works but I don't know if there are better ways to handle object placement.

I would also simplify my life by assigning to sphere radius `1` and not `0.03` and then making the scene "smaller" moving the camera away as zoom-out (I think this is the trick).

So, I need help setting the scene correctly.

That is my first application in ThreeJs so any advice is welcome!

---

**EDIT 1**

I changed `camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));` to `camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -5));` and I added `spotLight.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -5));`.

This is the result:

[image]

Not exactly what I want...

Answer (score 0):

You're right in placing your plane and sphere at 0 on the y-axis. The problem you're having is that you're telling the camera to look *straight at* (0, 0, 0) when you do

`camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);`

so you'll get the ball perfectly centered. What you should do is tell the camera to look a little bit ahead of the sphere. You'll have to tweak the value, but something like this should do the trick:

`camera.lookAt(0, 0, -5);`

Additionally, your spotlight is pointing straight ahead. When you place it at (2, 30, 0), its effects get lost. You need to point it to where you want:

`spotLight.lookAt(0, 0, -5);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed my code like you suggested and the result is not what I hoped. I added an image in my main message.

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea what you're doing in your JSFiddle... your object positioning is really all over the map, and your camera is now looking up at the *bottom* of your plane. I recommend that you spend a while playing with the three.js editor and *really* get acquainted with the x, y, z axes: https://threejs.org/editor/ Try to recreate your scene by adding planes, spheres, and obstacles, and try to keep in mind: +x is to the right, +y is up, and +z is towards the viewer.

Comment: Note: `camera.lookAt( x, y, z )` is valid, and it does not result in instantiating a new `Vector3`.

Comment: @WestLangley whoops, you're right! Fixed. I saw it in his code and just copied it to my answer.